# How to test 'paste' event in a generic input text with React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paste, react-testing-library

I am trying to test in "integration" a pasting functionality using rect testing library. So far, I have been able to trigger the 'paste' event, and see the paste event being passed to the `onPaste` prop of my input field.

The thing I'd like to test is the actual value of the element being changed into whatever is being pasted. Follows the example:

```js
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';

it('should show an empty cell if value is incorrect', async () => {
  const { getByDisplayValue } = await render(
    <TextField
      value=""
      onPaste={event => {
        console.log(event.clipboardData.getData('text'));
      }}
      onChange={e => {
        console.log(e.currentTarget.value);
      }}
    />
  );

  const input = await getByDisplayValue('');

  const eventProperties = {
    clipboardData: {
      getData: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce('Foo Bar Test'),
    },
  };
  const pasteEvent = createEvent.paste(input, eventProperties);
  pasteEvent.clipboardData = eventProperties.clipboardData;

  fireEvent(input, pasteEvent);

  await waitFor(() => {
    getByDisplayValue('Foo Bar Test');
  });
});
```

As a result, I get:

```
console.log MyComponent.test.js:110
    Foo Bar Test


TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the display value: Foo Bar Test.

<body>
  <div>
    <div
      class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root"
    >
      <div
        class="MuiInputBase-root MuiInput-root MuiInput-underline MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInput-formControl"
      >
        <input
          aria-invalid="false"
          class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input"
          type="text"
          value=""
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I would expect the `value` prop of the `TextField` being populated with the content of the pasting event, but as you can see, it is empty. Also, I would expect the `onChange` event to be triggered, but this is not the case either (no console log in the test is showed).

Comment: Well, in the example your `TextInput` has a static value, `""`, so it can't change. What does the actual component code look like? Does it work if you use `defaultValue` in the test?

Comment: Hey Drew, thanks for your reply. Yes you are definitely right on the value. The issue is that the `onChange` callback is not executed. Differently, for a `fireEvent.input(input, { target: { value: 'my test' } });` I can see the `onChange` console log happening. I was expecting to see that happening with the `paste` event too.

Comment: You question content resolved my issue.